# How many arguments can be passed to filter()

Tags: python, lambda, filter

Can we pass two arguments in the function that returns true and filters a list?
I am trying to get divisor from user and dividend be picked up from the list.

```
    new_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    print "Get the divisor"
    divisor=int(input())
    h=lambda x,divisor: x%divisor==0
    ans=filter(h(x,divisor),new_list)
    print ans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, if you have `divisor` defined in the surrounding scope.

But then, you will not *need* to use it as an argument any longer:

```
divisor = int(raw_input())
ans = filter(lambda x: x % divisor==0, new_list)
print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your approach:

(1) You don't need to define `divisor` as the second argument to `lambda` as it is initialized by your `input` statement.

(2) You should only pass the function reference to `filter`, not call the function.

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print "Get the divisor"
divisor = int(input())

h = lambda x: x % divisor == 0
ans = filter(h, new_list)
print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass in `divisor` as an argument; it is simply available as a *closure*:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print "Get the divisor"
divisor = int(raw_input())  # on Python 2, you want to use raw_input

# divisor is taken from the parent scope here
h = lambda x: x % divisor == 0
ans = filter(h, new_list)
print ans
```

Note that you need to pass the function object as the first argument to `filter()`, not the result of calling the function. `filter()` passes just one argument to that function object, always.

Comment: @Butters: `filter()` passes just one argument to the function, always.